# Bootstrap form-group height growing

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

I have this control that the user can upload files. If the users upload more then 1 it runs into the next form-group control that is on this view. Is there a way I can get this form-group to grow?

```
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fileManagerIds)

    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                        .Name("upImport")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "width: 700px;" })
                        .Messages(e => e.DropFilesHere("Drop files here")
                        .Select("Select file"))
                        .Async(a => a
                            .Save("Async_Save", "Upload")
                            .Remove("Async_Remove", "Upload")
                            .AutoUpload(true)
                            .SaveField("files")
                        )

                        .Events(e => e.Success("upImportSuccess"))
                    )

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.fileManagerIds, new { id = string.Format("fileManagerIds"), @name = "fileManagerIds" })
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps related https://stackoverflow.com/q/23065029/125981

Comment: Feels like you should be able to add classes using the helper to use the bootstrap style you wish here.

Comment: You mean the kendo helper?

Comment: Yes, I see from the code you are using the c# MVC helper.  It would be useful to update your question with the version of kendo you are using. Keep in mind that the helper only helps render and what is rendered is what you should focus on; including the CSS in play here - which is hard to discern from this, and it has been a while since I used these thus my memory of what renders is a bit faded.

Comment: Keep in mind that bootstrap-4 does not have a designated file upload component so here you rely on the kendo component to provide the html and the applicable CSS to render it.

Comment: Thanks is there something else I can use other the form-group that will not have a fixed height?

Comment: Try using `d-flex flex-row` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/